# view by newspaper category with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My problem is that I need to fill an array with rails 4 to display top 3 results categorized by newspaper

Category of newspaper is: 0,1,2,3 or other, is random.

`parsed_json`: Is one array with values de newspapers, after news_source fill with news from newspapers.

SQL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP8BM.png

With this code only the last value of the array of a newspaper.

```
def index
  if get_api_key
    @parsed_json = Array.new
    @news_source = Array.new
    #Trae todos los datos asociados a la llave
    @emission = Emission.where(key: get_api_key)

    #Envío de datos a json
    @emission.each do |p|
      @weather_now = WeatherNowUy.where(city: p.state)
      @weather_next_days = WeatherNextDaysUy.where(city: p.state)
      @parsed_json << JSON.parse(p.news_source)
    end

    @parsed_json.each do |u|
      @news_source = NewsUy.where(newspaper: u).limit(3)
    end

  end
end
```

Example of return, no show by newspaper 1 is also found in the array `parsed_json`.

Not

```
  "News": [
{
  "title": "Con un gol de Tevez, Boca venciÃ³ a Godoy Cruz 2-0 y sigue en lo mÃ¡s alto",
  "description": "El delantero marcÃ³ de penal en la victoria en La Bombonera. Meli habÃ­a abierto el marcador. Los \"Xeneizes\" comparten con San Lorenzo la primera posiciÃ³n.",
  "newspaper": "0"
},
{
  "title": "Barcelona picÃ³ en punta",
  "description": "La primera fecha del fÃºtbol espaÃ±ol se terminarÃ¡ el lunes con el partido entre Granada y Eibar.",
  "newspaper": "0"
},
{
  "title": "Sampdoria, Chievo Verona y Fiorentina los lÃ­deres",
  "description": "Este fin de semana se disputÃ³ la primera fecha de la serie A italiana.",
  "newspaper": "0"
}
```

]
}

Answer (score 0):

Change `@news_source = NewsUy.where(newspaper: u).limit(3)` to `@news_source << NewsUy.where(newspaper: u).limit(3)` in your last `@parsed_json.each do` loop. Because, if you use `=` operator, it will replace it every time with the next value and that's why you are getting only the last value. To get all the values, you need to accumulate those into the `@news_source` array using `<<` operator.

So, you need this:

```
@parsed_json.each do |u|
  @news_source << NewsUy.where(newspaper: u).limit(3)
end
```

Comment: This return error, my mysql table is stored with the value serialized in this way ["1", "0"].

Comment: what error does it return?  give some example values from your mysql table.

Comment: undefined method `title' for #<NewsUy::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f970e849b88>

Value store in database is ["0", "1"].

I convert from the database so:
@parsed_json << JSON.parse(p.news_source)

Comment: I think the problem is to deserialize